# Attempting to use loops to create text on a canvas and move it

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I am trying to make an animated background for a webpage where numbers move around in the background and lines connect them when they get close enough.

I have been struggling for the past week to get this done. I cant tell why the digits wont populate on the page. It might be to do with the way im using `.this`?

I am not sure if I am creating the "Floater" (a name I made for the floating numbers) correctly as I am new to JS.

I also have no idea how to do the lines just yet so you can ignore that but if anyone has any suggestions I am all ears.

```
// JavaScript Document
/*eslint-env es6*/

//Declared global variables
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "10px Arial";
let floaterArray = [];

alert('Window loaded! Window width: ' + window.innerWidth + ' Window height: ' + window.innerHeight);
init();

//Initializing function
function init() {
    setSize();  
    populate(100);
}   

//Floater particle
function Floater(x, y, vx, vy, digit, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.text = digit;
    this.color = color;
    
    this.zoom = () => {
        const position = {
            x: this.x,
            y: this.y,
        };
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillText(this.digit);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(position.x,position.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x + vx,this.y + vy);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

//Populates the html page with a number of new divs and the css with styles for each div 
function populate(num) { 
    alert('Canvas width: ' + canvas.width + ' Window height: ' + canvas.height);

    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        floaterArray[i] = new Floater(
            randNumber(0,canvas.width),
            randNumber(0,canvas.height),
            randNumber(1,5),
            randNumber(1,5),
            randNumber(0,1),
            "grey"
        );
    } 
    alert('Populated with ' + num + ' floaters');
}

//Moves every frame
function move(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
    floaterArray.forEach((Floater) => Floater.zoom());
}

//Draw a line between two locations
function drawLine(ax,ay,bx,by) {
    let x = bx - ax;
    let y = by - ay;    
    
    if (Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) <= 10) {
        //draws a line between both points and adds it to an array
    } else {
        //checks for an existing line in the array between both points and deletes it if there is one
    }
}

//Create a random number between two vaules
function randNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
    
//Set canvas to window size 
function setSize() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

window.addEventListener("resize", () => setSize());
```

What should happen is the page is populated randomly with numbers that move at their own speeds per digit. What happens right now is essentially nothing.

I know the canvas resizes as I gave it a border but it also seems to bleed off the bottom and side of the page? No clue about that either. Please assist.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its a term I came up with, not actual embedder functionality. Its what I named the animated numbers floating around, that's why I put it in quotes originally.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that nothing is showing up because you aren't calling `ctx.stroke()` after you define the path.

```
this.zoom = () => {
    const position = {
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y,
    };
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillText(this.digit);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(position.x,position.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x + vx,this.y + vy);
    ctx.closePath(); // you shouldn't need this, as you're only drawing a straight line
    ctx.stroke();
};
```

You probably also want to position the text before you call `fillText()`

Comment: I edited the code a bit but still got nothing...
```this.zoom = () => {
  const position = {
    x: this.x,
    y: this.y,
  };
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(position.x,position.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x + vx,this.y + vy);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fillText(this.digit);
```
Also, I could be wrong here, but wouldn't stroke only stroke the line, not the text?